# run time error 91 - object not set

Tags: html, vba, parsing

When running the below code I get a run time error 91 - with object not set or with block... But I am lost how to fix it. It occures at:

```
.document.body.innerHTML = Status.innerHTML
```

Anyone sees through?

```
Dim Groups  As Collection
Set Groups = New Collection
Groups.Add "LineGroupSA"
Groups.Add "LineGroupPR"
Groups.Add "LineGroupEM"
i = 0
For Each group In Groups
Set Status = IEDoc.getElementById(group)
With Ie
    .document.body.innerHTML = Status.innerHTML
    .document.body.createTextRange.execCommand "Copy"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").cells(1, i)
    .Quit
End With
i = i + 1
Next group
```

*html:*

```
<TR id=LineGroupSA class="ui-datatable-summaryrow ui-widget-header">
    <TD style="WIDTH: 5%"></TD> 
    <TD style="WIDTH: 10%">SA</TD> 
    <TD colSpan=6><SPAN style="COLOR: red; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">AWAITING CHANGES</SPAN></TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that an element wasn't found with that ID.

Comment: the HTML code looks like this: 
`<TR id=LineGroupSA class="ui-datatable-summaryrow ui-widget-header"><TD style="WIDTH: 5%"></TD>
<TD style="WIDTH: 10%">SA</TD>
<TD colSpan=6><SPAN style="COLOR: red; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">AWAITING CHANGES</SPAN></TD></TR>`

Comment: The id isn't wrapped in quotes?

Comment: it should be but it got lost when I copy pasted from F12 in IE. I assume I must IEDoc again somehow? It's the HTMLDocument of the url i navigated too before. But possibly the IEDoc got lost in the loop? and that's why it doesn't find the second item in the collection?

Comment: In your loop, you quit IE after the first iteration, so the document doesn't exist in the second loop.

Comment: I have tried to quite it later but it doesnät work either :( Alternativelty I have tried .innerText but that's just not correct formating and I would need some additonally coding for the format. Also tried to just put the .innerHTML in the cell and run the .createTextRange.execCommand "Copy" over it which works but this is not clean. It should be "storable" in  .document.body.innerHTML from the beginning, right?

Comment: ok found a workaround by pasting it special as "Unicode text" via DataObject

Answer (score 0):

The variable Ie isn't set anywhere... I guess that's why the error "with object not set" is prompted